# Como trazer apenas determinada parte de um texto em um campo

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Como faço para trazer somente uma parte do texto em um campo no sql server?

Tenho a query abaixo que na coluna Descrição, ele retornar um texto com muitas informações como por exemplo.

```
Nome Cliente    Data do ultimo Tramite     Descrição
Teste           25-07-2017                 de para teste ok  descricao do chamado
```

Eu quero trazer os registros que estão na coluna descrição, que possam vir a partir da palavra descrição. Como faço? Abaixo é a query:

```
SELECT
    S.SolID,
    UC.UsuNome [Nome Cliente],
    MAX(T.TraData) [Data do Último Trâmite],
    MAX(CAST(T.Descricao as varchar(max))) [Descrição do Último Trâmite],
    U.UsuNome [Consultor Responsável],
    MAX(M.MotDesc) [Motivo da Pausa]
FROM
    Solicitacao S
    LEFT JOIN Usuario U ON U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel
    LEFT JOIN Usuario UC ON UC.UsuID = S.UsuIDCliente
    LEFT JOIN StatusMotivo SM ON SM.SMSolID = S.SolID
    INNER JOIN Motivo M ON M.MotID = SM.SMMotID
    INNER JOIN Tramite T on T.SolID = S.SolID and 
             T.TraID = (SELECT TOP 1 
                     X.TraID 
                 FROM
                     Tramite X 
                 WHERE
                    X.SolID = S.SolID
                ORDER BY
                    X.TraData DESC)
WHERE
    S.VencimentoPausado = 1
    AND s.usuidresponsavel = 91258
    AND cast(T.TraData as date) <= cast(DATEADD(day,-2,getdate()) as date)
GROUP BY
    S.SolID,
    UC.UsuNome,
    U.UsuNome
```

Comment: Você precisa que traga os registros que contenham o termo pesquisado no campo descrição, ou precisa trazer todos os registros, mas somente o que foi pesquisado (como um match de regex)?

Comment: quero trazer todos os registros, mas em vez de vir "de para teste ok  descricao do chamado". Quero que venha nessa coluna somente a partir do "descricao do chamado"

Comment: só uma observação: você não precisa de `MAX(T.TraData)` porque no join, só está vindo um único registro da tabela tramite, e que é o último, ordenado pela `TraData`

Answer (score 1):

Baseado na resposta do comentário, segue o trecho de código. Porém ele vai pegar sempre da primeira ocorrência do termo blzz ;) Testa pra ver se está OK. como não tenho um banco pra teste precisa-se de validação.

```
SELECT
    S.SolID,
    UC.UsuNome [Nome Cliente],
    MAX(T.TraData) [Data do Último Trâmite],
    MAX(CAST(T.Descricao as varchar(max))) [Descrição do Último Trâmite],
    U.UsuNome [Consultor Responsável],
    MAX(M.MotDesc) [Motivo da Pausa],
    MAX(SUBSTRING(T.Descricao, PATINDEX('%termoPesquisa%', T.Descricao), LEN(T.Descricao))) [Termo Filtrado]
FROM
    Solicitacao S
    LEFT JOIN Usuario U ON U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel
    LEFT JOIN Usuario UC ON UC.UsuID = S.UsuIDCliente
    LEFT JOIN StatusMotivo SM ON SM.SMSolID = S.SolID
    INNER JOIN Motivo M ON M.MotID = SM.SMMotID
    INNER JOIN Tramite T on T.SolID = S.SolID and 
             T.TraID = (SELECT TOP 1 
                     X.TraID 
                 FROM
                     Tramite X 
                 WHERE
                    X.SolID = S.SolID
                ORDER BY
                    X.TraData DESC)
WHERE
    S.VencimentoPausado = 1
    AND s.usuidresponsavel = 91258
    AND cast(T.TraData as date) <= cast(DATEADD(day,-2,getdate()) as date)
GROUP BY
    S.SolID,
    UC.UsuNome,
    U.UsuNome
```

Comment: ôpa amigo. Não funcionou. Ocorreu o seguinte erro. 
Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Tipo de dados de argumento varbinary(max) inválido para o argumento 2 da função patindex.

Comment: Faz cast no onde ta os T.Descrição na linha que acrescentei. Essa descrição no seu banco é text ou varchar?